# simple php, sending a form email

Tags: php

I just started learning php today, so exciting : p

not really sure what i am doing wrong

I got my first error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\wamp\www\lesson1\form_response.php on line 20   

 <?php
    $firstname =  $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $street =  $_POST['street'];
    $city =  $_POST['city'];
    $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];   

    $myemail = 'chrnna@gmail.com'


    $email_message = "First Name: {$firstname} <br> Last Name: {$lastname} <br> Street: {$street} <br> City: {$city} <br> Phone Number: {$phonenumber} <br> Email: {email}";



    mail($myemail,'test form',$email_message);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgot a semi-colon.

```
$myemail = 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com';
```

Probably don't want to post your actual email...

Comment: I changed like 20 things only to be shot down my a semicolon

Comment: do i have to use <?php ?> if i want line breaks in the email each time? or is there a command like java \n

Comment: "\n" will work, or a literal line break. Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's because you are missing a **;** after `$myemail = 'chrnna@gmail.com'`

Comment: thanks, wont be the last time this happens next time ill know to look for that first